# how to parse xml from apex- parsing results null

Tags: apex, soap, xml

Hi I am trying to parse below xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>GetUserResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:d43cb18b-d404-41c1-82c6-ae68b4aa9274</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:a4cc29d7-06b0-41c9-a289-f1848ae5e96d</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-9baad9b8-1ca9-4676-ae02-67d352eaa385">
                <wsu:Created>2015-10-20T16:14:03Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2015-10-20T16:19:03Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <GetUserResponse xmlns="urn:Cornerstone:ClientDataService">
            <User Id="00u5a01i3vmAM4Lty0h7" Guid="874e89ac-0eeb-42b3-97d0-a9c80a1a522e" Active="true" Absent="false" AllowReconcile="false" Language="" UserTimeZone="" DeepLinkBaseURL="https://cadence.oktapreview.com/app/cornerstone/exk4qwr6soLYOags90h7/sso/saml?RelayState="
                xmlns="urn:Cornerstone:ClientData">
                <Contact>
                    <Name Prefix="" First="Shilpa" Middle="" Last="Patil" Suffix="" />
                    <Email>shilpapatil201010@mailinator.com</Email>
                    <Phone Type="Fax"></Phone>
                    <Phone Type="Work">764372647</Phone>
                    <Address CountryCode="IND">
                        <Line1>92648275</Line1>
                        <City>874287548</City>
                        <State>Chattisgarh</State>
                        <PostalCode>8732584276</PostalCode>
                    </Address>
                </Contact>
                <Organization Approvals="1">
                    <Unit Type="Location">IN</Unit>
                    <Unit Type="Division">IN</Unit>
                    <Unit Type="Company">ES_GENERAL</Unit>
                    <Employment LastHireDate="2015-10-20" />
                    <Approver />
                    <Manager />
                </Organization>
                <Demographic>
                    <Ethnicity />
                </Demographic>
                <Authentication>
                    <Username>shilpapatil201010@mailinator.com</Username>
                </Authentication>
                <Custom>
                    <Field Name="Advanced Node Design">no</Field>
                    <Field Name="Analog/Custom IC Design">no</Field>
                    <Field Name="Company">ABC</Field>
                    <Field Name="Department Code"></Field>
                    <Field Name="Digital IC Design-Encounter"></Field>
                    <Field Name="Digital Implementation">no</Field>
                </Custom>
            </User>
        </GetUserResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

i want to read id from the tag

```
<User Id="00u5a01i3vmAM4Lty0h7" Guid="874e89ac-0eeb-42b3-97d0-a9c80a1a522e" Active="true" Absent="false" AllowReconcile="false" Language="" UserTimeZone="" DeepLinkBaseURL="https://cadence.oktapreview.com/app/cornerstone/exk4qwr6soLYOags90h7/sso/saml?RelayState="
                    xmlns="urn:Cornerstone:ClientData">
```

I am parsing in the following way

```
Dom.Document docx = new Dom.Document();
        docx.load(aboveXmlResponse);
        //Retrieve the root element for this document.
        dom.XmlNode xroot = docx.getrootelement() ;
        dom.XmlNode Body = xroot.getChildElement('Envelope', null)
            .getChildElement('soap:Body', null);
        system.debug('*** body is '+Body);
```

i am getting null while parsing the xml on every node... Is this right way to parse or am i missing any thing while parsing.

I have got the id , i have missed the name spaces.

The code that worked for me is

```
String envNs = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
        dom.XmlNode userNode = xroot.getChildElement('Body', envNs).getChildElement('GetUserResponse', 'urn:Cornerstone:ClientDataService').getChildElement('User', 'urn:Cornerstone:ClientData');
 system.debug('*** userNode id'+userNode.getAttributeValue('Id',null));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the XML includes namespaces, you need to supply the [namespace as the second argument](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_xmlnode.htm#apex_Dom_XmlNode_getChildElement):

```
String envNs = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
dom.XmlNode Body = xroot.getChildElement('Envelope', envNs)
        .getChildElement('Body', envNs);
```

Take care to use the right namespace for each element e.g. for 'GetUserResponse' it is 'urn:Cornerstone:ClientDataService'. See e.g. [XML Namespaces](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) for more explanation of the various ways namespaces are defined.

Comment: this works .. thanks a lot.yes i have missed name spaces

Comment: This has helped me, many thanks! @Keith!

Comment: Your are very welcome @Raul.

Comment: The documentation didn't do a good job in explaining on finding a namespace Or I didn't read it carefully enough: [Reading and Writing XML Using the DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_dom.htm).